Removing the filename extension and replacing the underscore with space at the same time
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    
    {% for object in data %}
        <!-- USE BOOTSTRAP -->
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h1>{{ object.filename|split('.').slice(0, -4).join('.')|str.replaceAll('_', ' ') }}</h1>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ object.pic_hash }}">
            <p>Mean Squared Error for Random Forest Model is: {{ object.rmse_rf }}</p>
            <p>Mean Squared Error for Linear Regression Model is: {{ object.rmse_lr }}</p>
            <p>R-squared for Random Forest Model: {{ object.r2_rf }}</p>
            <p>R-squared for Linear Regression Model: {{ object.r2_lr }}</p>
            <p>Mean Absolute Error for Random Forest Model is: {{ object.mae_rf }}</p>
            <p>Mean Absolute Error for Linear Regression Model is: {{ object.mae_lr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}

I'm using this query and it says invalid filter split. What should I do?
I tried everything and I hope you can help me with my problem.

First off, what version of Bootstrap? Is this an Angular app? Can you clarify what you mean by "this query"? What is the format of your file name? Provide an example. When you say you tried "everything", what did you try?

This isn't a Bootstrap question. Please tag properly for whatever technology that is doing the logic.

I'm not quite understanding the full code structure of
<h1>{{ object.filename|split('.').slice(0, -4).join('.')|str.replaceAll('_', ' ') }}</h1>

It seems you are using it incorrectly.
Try using this
{{ object.filename.split('.')[:-4]|join('.')|replace('_', ' ') }}

Please add what is the result you desire, to further clear explanation.
